# Is there a modal operator, L, that satisfies φ ↔  & ~L ⊢ ~Lφ?

Tags: logic, definition, philosophy

I am wondering if there's some modal operator that would satisfy $$φ ↔  \& ~L ⊢ ~Lφ.$$ That is:

1. Given $φ ↔  \& ~L$
2. You can get to $~Lφ$

One limitation is that $L$ for sure does not satisfy modal axiom $T$: i.e., it's not the case that if $Lφ → φ$.

Otherwise, we'd use the usual, well-known modal axioms and theorems.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: That does not hold in S5 (or anything weaker) since there is a countermodel where $\phi$, $\psi$ holds at the actual world, and $\phi, \neg\psi$ holds at the only accessible possible world. It holds in the system Triv, which includes $\phi  \leftrightarrow  L\phi$ as an axiom.

Comment: Thanks @Bumble. Do you know if instead of getting to ~Lφ, one could just get to 
(φ → ~Lφ)?

Comment: That still does not hold in S5, because of the same countermodel. It still holds in Triv.

Comment: @Bumble Thanks again. I looked into Triv, and it looks like Triv contains axiom T. So that probably won't work for my purposes here. Hm! 

Comment: Triv is a system that corresponds to modal collapse, so it is not very useful. For any P: MP, P and LP all hold, or M¬P, ¬P and L¬P all hold.